# What is the reasoning behind hiding a module inside a closure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angularjs-scope

As an example:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('Base', []).controller('BaseController', function($scope) {
    $scope.mixin1 = function() {};
  })
})();
```

What is the point in encapsulating the `angularjs` module? I thought it by default is so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid polluting the global namespace, wrap all your functions during compilation/concatenation inside an IIFE which will produce something like this: If you don't encapsulate your functions, then you will pollute global scope and its not good. 
[read this](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/)

```
(function () {
  angular.module('app', []);

  // MainCtrl.js
  function MainCtrl () {

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  // AnotherCtrl.js
  function AnotherCtrl () {

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AnotherCtrl', AnotherCtrl);

  // and so on...

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, the reason is to avoid creating global variables.

But in your example if you always put the code inside the controller function, is not needed.

So what's the point?... I don't see the point in the example, other than following a style pattern.

Instead of relying in doing that extra stuff by hand, there are tools that can do that for you. From a simple concat (like grunt-contrib-concat or Yeoman's usemin), to a more complex ones like Browserify. (Browserify is for translating nodejs code, but it works very well for wrapping existing browser code with the AMD boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625042/what-is-the-benefit-of-the-javascript-module-pattern) and [this](http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern)

Comment: It would be great to provide a little more information or a summary from the links, as opposed to just linking offsite.

Comment: besides it seems to be not really connected to the angular module case